# What's the difference between setBackgroundImage:Forstate and setImage:Forstate:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to set a image for a UIButton.

I don't know the difference between the setBackgroundImage:Forstate and setImage:Forstate:

Could anyone help me out?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 24):

1. `setImage:forState:` sets the image as the actual content of the button. For example, you can not see the button *title* even though you set it, because you have set an image as the content.
2. `setBackgroundImage:forState:` sets the image as the background. In this case, you can set the *title* and it is displayed on top of the image.

Comment: Thanks,Simon, you let me know the relation between the title and the image in each of the method.

Comment: @shashoukou: As I mentioned above, if you use `setImage:forState:` method you can not set the title for the button(it will not be visible). But, if you use `setBackgroundImage:forState:` you can set the title and it will be visible.

Answer (score 12):

setBackgroundImage: follows the frame, i.e. if u change the frame, the background image is streched or shrinked with it. Contrary on the setImage, its not the same. The image takes its own size. In setImage the image is the actual content of the button.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is in the framing

**I will explain you with the help of example suppose your image size is 40*40 and button frame is 20*20 then if you use setBackgroundImage:forState: method the image will be displayed in 20*20 frame and if you use setImage:forState: method you will see a button with image size of 40*40 frame.**
This is the difference.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks, Jenifer, you let me know how the frame change using these methods.