# Difference between setBackgroundImage and setImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to implement a radio button feature in my app and I am switching between images using the `setBackgroundImage:forControlState` method and it is working fine.

However, I can see another method `setImage:forControlState` and wondering when to use setImage and when to use setBackgroundImage.

Basically what is difference between these two methods in terms of functionality.

Comment: You can find http://stackoverflow.com/a/5909740/5362916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIButton documentation does not tell you what are the differences between these two methods.
Experimenting uncovers one interesting difference: if you change the button’s frame, background images follow the size change, while images keep their original size.
Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

So simple, if you use `setImage` actually you say that 'I'll use an image for whole button components.' and will not able to set title etc. If you use `setBackgroundImage`, you say that 'I'll use an image for just background of button components.' and able to set title etc.